# How to add new objects to vector in C++

Tags: c++, class, object, dynamic, vector

I am trying to create a program which allows a user to add an object of class called Vehicle to an inventory that is stored in a `vector`. The `vector` has an initial size of zero. Each object is a vehicle that the user enters the attributes of.

What I cannot wrap my head around is how to let the user keep adding vehicles if each vehicle needs to be its own separate object. How do you let C++ determine what the name of new objects should be if the user decides to keep adding more vehicles (objects) to the inventory (`vector` called `carList`).

Could someone guide me in the right direction? I apologize if this is obvious, I am new to the language. Must I do something that involves dynamically allocating objects or something similar?

Here is my (incomplete) code:

```
void addVehicle(vector<Vehicle> carList)
{
    char   stop;            // Needed for stopping the do-while loop 
    string VIN = "",        // Needed to hold user input for the VIN
           Make = "",       // Needed to hold user input for the Make
           Model = "";      // Needed to hold user input for the Model
    int    Year = 0;        // Needed to hold user input for the Year
    double Price = 0.0;     // Needed to hold user input for the Price

    cout << "You have chosen to add a vehicle to your inventory.\n\n";

    do
    {
        cout << "There are currently " << carList.size() << " vehicles in your inventory.\n\n"
             << "\t\t\tVehicle #" << (carList.size() + 1) << ": \n"
             << "\t\t___________________________\n\n";

        Vehicle /*new object needs to go here*/
        carList.push_back(/*new object from the line above*/);

        // Prompt user to input VIN
        cout << "VIN: ";
        cin >> VIN;

        // Prompt user to input Make
        cout << "Make: ";
        cin.ignore(); 
        getline(cin, Make);

        // Prompt user to input Model
        cout << "Model: ";
        getline(cin, Model);

        // Prompt user to input Year
        cout << "Year: ";
        cin >> Year;

        // Prompt user to input Price
        cout << "Price: $";
        cin >> Price;

        Call to the overloaded constructor to store user input in object
        /*(newly created object)*/.Vehicle::Vehicle(VIN, Make, Model, Year, Price);

        // Ask user if they would like to enter another vehicle
        cout << "\nWould you like to enter another vehicle? (Y/N):";
        cin.ignore();
        stop = cin.get();

    } while (stop != 'N');
```

}

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you solve this if it wasn't about objects of type `Vehicle` but just `std::string`s? If you can, all you need to do is to replace one with the other to switch between the two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about you first create the object and then push a copy into the vector?

```
Call to the overloaded constructor to store user input in object
Vehicle temp(VIN, Make, Model, Year, Price);
carList.push_back(temp);
```

But there's no need for the variable, really:

```
Call to the overloaded constructor to store user input in object
carList.push_back(Vehicle(VIN, Make, Model, Year, Price));
```

And if you have C++11, you can even construct the object directly in place:

```
Call to the overloaded constructor to store user input in object
carList.emplace_back(VIN, Make, Model, Year, Price);
```

Look ma, no copies!

Comment: @Justin In that case please consider accepting an answer.

Comment: @RawN Don't rush him ;) Is it even possible to accept an answer just 14 minutes after asking the question?

Comment: Ohh... I think it is better to use std::move() to reduce some copy operation

Comment: @kaitian There is no need for `std::move`, because `Vehicle(VIN, Make, Model, Year, Price)` is already an rvalue. And all `std::move` does is cast to an rvalue. Also, OP apparently has no C++11 compiler, otherwise the 3rd solution would have worked, and `emplace_back` is even more efficient than `push_back` on an rvalue.

Comment: @fredoverflow I am actually noticing a problem now. If I use the code of the second one, while I am in the do-while look it says I keep having more and more objects in my inventory, which is what I want. However, when I exit the function and go back in, it says that no objects are in the vector. It does not appear to retain the data collected in the do-while loop. Why is this?

Comment: fredoverflow you are right, The compiler is smart. @Justin you should move you function definination from "void addVehicle(vector<Vehicle> carList)" to "void addVehicle(vector<Vehicle> &carList)"

Comment: @Justin you need to pass the vector by reference by declaring the function like this: `void addVehicle(vector<Vehicle> &carList)`. Otherwise the vector inside the function and the one outside would be two different copies; changes to one will not affect the other.

Comment: @jadhachem I have done that. Now it says that I have x amount of inventory items, but when I use a for loop to display them, they all come out empty or with garbage values. I have initialized all of my variables to zero, so I can't see why this might be.

Comment: @Justin It's impossible to debug this issue with the code you have provided. I suggest you paste your entire code into pastebin or ideone and give us the link.

Comment: @Justin Inside the `Vehicle` constructor, your assignments are wrong. You assign the fields to the parameters, but it should be the other way around. You have `iVIN = VIN`, but it should be `VIN = iVIN`. The same for all the other fields. Does that fix the issue?

Comment: @fredoverflow OMG yes that fixed it! Why does the order of the assignments matter?

Comment: Because unlike in math, `a = b` means something else than `b = a` in imperative programming. The thing on the right is copied into the thing on the left. If you want to copy your parameter into your field, the parameter has to be on the right, and the field has to be on the left. Makes sense?

Comment: @fredoverflow Yes I suppose that makes sense. I guess my instructor failed to teach me that the stream of data goes from left to right :/